# Webhooks and delayed_job in a Rails shopify app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

Hi I'm trying to add webhooks to my shopify app created using the shopify gem.

Until now everything works.  In my webhook_controller I have a before filter that connects to the store:
        before_filter :connect_to_store

```
    def product_new
      data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(request.body.read)
      shopify_id = data["id"]

      Product.new_from_shopify(@s, shopify_id)

      head :ok
    end

    private

    def connect_to_store

      shop_url = request.headers['HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_SHOP_DOMAIN']
      shop_url = ("http://" + shop_url)

      @s = Shop.find_by_url(shop_url)

      session = ShopifyAPI::Session.new(@s.url, @s.access_token)
      session.valid?
      ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(session)

    end
```

In this way I can easily access the Shopify API inside my Product model:

```
  def self.new_from_shopify(shop, shopify_id)

      shopify_p = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(shopify_id)

      # creates the local product
      local_p = Product.new
      local_p.shopify_id = shopify_p.id
      local_p.name = shopify_p.title
      local_p.shop = shop
      local_p.save

  end
```

So far so good.

The problem is when I try to add delayed_job into the mix.
If I try to change

```
Product.new_from_shopify(@s, shopify_id)
```

to

```
Product.delay.new_from_shopify(@s, shopify_id)
```

Then the delayed job has no more access to the Shopify API connection and gives me an error.

What is the best practice in this case?

**UPDATE**

One possible solution is to create a new method in my Shop model:

```
    def connect_to_store
      session = ShopifyAPI::Session.new(self.url, self.access_token)
      session.valid?
      ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(session)
    end
```

And then call this method in my Product model action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same method that I suggested here will work in a job worker as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11445727/1440757

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a job that will be executed outside of the controller scope, it has to know how to connect to the shopify API without this method.

The best solution would be to extract that code that sets up the Shopify api connection to a separate module that is accessible to both the controller and the delayed job.

Comment: Thanks very much Draiken, I found out this was the right way to do it.  I'm updating my question with the solution suggested.

Comment: I suggested using an external module because the shopify connection should not be coupled with the model, your solution will work fine, but if you ever have to use that connection again, you'll still have to decouple this from your model to an external module.

Comment: Sorry Draiken, I don't understand this.  What do you mean by external module? Do you mean that using my solution each time I call Product.delay.new_from_shopify(@s, shopify_id) I open a new connection?  Is there a way for the "connect_to_store" method to open a new connection unless there is not another connection already open?

Comment: Depends on your architecture. Imagine you have a `ShopifyConnection` class that manages this connection and then you could use that from both the controller and the delayed job. You could save the connection when possible as you described too. That's the point of decoupling, you will have another object that has only one concern: the shopify connection.

Comment: Ok, I understand.  The only thing I miss is how can I check if a connection is already open?

Comment: That I don't know, never used shopify. It might not even be a persistent connection, you can figure that out by looking at their code :)